# Non-boot CPUs are not disabled( seems there is a bug in "6.2.0-26-generic" kernel)

Tags: 22.04, hard-drive, suspend, bug-reporting

I use Ubuntu 22.04 with no issues for a while, but recently I can't suspend the OS and it gives me the following error and either hangs with a blank screen or shows up the system login screen:

```
Non-boot CPUs are not disabled
```

**`UPDATE`: I tried to use the previous working kernel that I had by restarting my computer and holding the `shift` key, then choosing `5.19.0-50-generic` kernel and suspend works now without any issues!
It seems there is a bug in the new kernel version `6.2.0-26-generic`.**

Comment: What Kernel version are you using?  `uname -r` should be able to show you.  I have seen somewhere about a Manjaro distro having the same issue but when they went to Kernel version 6.1+ the issue was resolved.

Comment: @Terrance: `6.2.0-26-generic`

Comment: You might have to file this one as a bug, but I am not certain what you would file it against if this is a Kernel bug or something.  I gave you +1 to help on your way.  I hope someone else has stumbled across this and knows how to fix it.  I would be interested in that as well.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I made my life easier by deleting the last kernel using following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic
```

Now I am using my previous kernel `5.19.0-50-generic` and everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu LTS releases ship multiple kernels, there is the "base" kernel which remains on the same release series throughout the lifetime of the release, but there are also the hardware enablement kernels. If you are on the hardware enablement kernel track (which I believe is the default nowadays for most systems) you will have been recently updated.

You say you have 22.04 and you are currently using kernel 6.2. It looks like 6.2 was pushed out as the "hardware enablement" kernel for 22.04 recently, so I would assume you upgraded to this kernel recently and I suspect this is what triggered your problem.

Is the old kernel still installed? if so you can try booting with it and seeing if the problem goes away?